# How can I offset a self CCFollow?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I used a CCFollow on my layer to follow a Player sprite. Is there anyway to offset so the Player is not directly in the center? I would like to offset the sprite by +100 Y of the center.

```
[self runAction: [CCFollow actionWithTarget:Player]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add empty node to your hero sprite with any offset you want and follow this node, not hero.